# What is the warning generated on my pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below warning is generated in every pages of my website, I noticed it from console:

> > event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead

I think it should be from the jquery file I linked, I didn't used event.returnValue anywhere.

What is the error? is this serios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just a warning, if you are using an old version of JQuery you should upgrade, for the moment no worry but your code may not work in the future

Comment: thanks for the reply, code is working good, but I wanted a clean console when a developer looking at my site's. I'll upgrade jquery.